# Draggable Items in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

For some reasons, my div blocks that are inside the div aren't draggable even when I have enabled them.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#boxes_holder").draggable();
});
</script>
```

HTML / PHP

```
<div id = "boxes_holder" class = "initBox">
<?php
//Creates 49 BOXES elements
    $x = 49;
    for($i=1; $i<=$x; $i++){
       echo '<div id="'.$i.' " draggable="true" class="boxes" style="text-align:center;" > '.$i.'</div>';
        }
?>
</div>
```

The stuff inside my boxes_holder arent draggable, why is that?

Another problem following this one is how one could possibly drag items to another div box.

My other div box:

```
<div id="dragBox" >
<div id="dragBoxTitle" >
    Pick Your Numbers:
</div>
</div>
```

All my code below are in order:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/hw2.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
$("#boxes_holder > .boxes").draggable();
});


</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="mainbody">
<h3>Lotto 6/49 Combinations Finder</h3>


<div id = "boxes_holder" class = "initBox">
<?php
//Creates 49 BOXES elements
    $x = 49;
    for($i=1; $i<=$x; $i++){
       echo '<div id="'.$i.' " draggable="true" class="boxes" style="text-    align:center;" > '.$i.'</div>';
    }
?>
</div>



<div id="dragBox" >
<div id="dragBoxTitle" >
    Pick Your Numbers:
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS Code:

```
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;  
color:#000;
cursor:auto;
}

#mainbody {
display:block;
width: 980px;
position: relative;
margin: 40px auto;
}

#mainbody h3{
font-size:24px;
color: blue;
}


#dragBox {
width:400px;
height:250px;
border:0px;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
vertical-align:top;
background-color:#FBFBFB;
}

#dragBoxTitle{
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 150%;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #D0D0D0;
border:1px solid #A9A9A9;
margin: 15px;
vertical-align:top;
}

.boxes {
width: 60px; 
height: 50px;
border:1px solid #A9A9A9;
line-height: 45px;
color: #FF0000;
padding:1px;
margin: 1px;
}


#boxes_holder{
width: 500px; 
height: 500px;
display: inline-block;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** You are missing the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library, the draggable feature is provided by jQuery UI

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/hw2.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You are making the `boxes_holder` element as draggable, not the div's inside it.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#boxes_holder > .boxes").draggable();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a3Hep/)

Comment: same problem, the box doesn't move for some reasons.

Comment: @user1234440 check the fiddle

Comment: hmm, it doesn't seem to be working for mine, do you think it may be because of my CSS code? I've updated the question just in case.

Comment: @user1234440 one main question is whether the `boxes` elements are created after the `draggable()` is called?

Comment: The other answer that `user2958643` gave is the sequence of code that I kind of have so I think the boxese elements are create after the jquery `draggable()` code. I have another box that is to the right of the 49 divs boxes.

Comment: @user1234440 any error in the browser console and versions of jQuery and jQuery UI used

Comment: No when I run in google chrome there is no error. I've updated the question to include all my code.

Comment: Hey Arun, I found that I misunderstood, my draggable div blocks were draggable in the sense that i've set `draggable = true` in my php loop creation. But when I took that code out, it doesn't work....wonder why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me. I have a suspicion it is how you are including your jquery ui

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#boxes_holder").draggable();
});
</script></head>
<body>
<div id = "boxes_holder" class = "initBox">
<?php
//Creates 49 BOXES elements
    $x = 49;
    for($i=1; $i<=$x; $i++){
       echo '<div id="'.$i.' " draggable="true" class="boxes" style="text-align:center;" > '.$i.'</div>';
        }
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```